Black and white film about boss helping employee's sick child by paying for emergency medicine delivery
I'm looking for an old black and white American movie. Here's the plot I remember:
A man works in a company that's going through tough financial times. During this period, there's a difficult conversation between him and his boss about salary - either it can't be raised or might be lowered.
Later in the movie, this employee's child becomes seriously ill and urgently needs medicine (possibly penicillin). The boss, showing unexpected kindness, pays from his own pocket for both the medicine and a pilot to deliver it. The delivery has to be made in harsh winter conditions.
In the end, the pilot successfully delivers the medicine and the child recovers.
Additional details:
It's most likely an American film
Black and white
Probably from around the 1940s-1950s
Does anyone recognize this movie?

That sounds familiar ... maybe a Shirley Temple?  Possibly she had a pet dog that was the key to the cure?

This is Made for Each Other (1939).
The lead is an attorney during the Great Depression, and the firm faces tough financial times:

After they have a baby, Jane encourages John to demand a raise and a promotion, but with finances tightened by the Depression, before John has a chance to demand more, Doolittle instead requires that all employees accept pay cuts.

Their baby is sick and needs a serum:

The baby is rushed to the hospital with pneumonia. The baby will die within hours unless a serum is delivered by plane from Salt Lake City.

And the boss covers the cost:

Doolittle agrees to provide the $5000 funding to deliver the serum, but with a storm raging, and with a wife and children to consider, the pilot refuses to fly. John pleads over the telephone, and the pilot's unmarried friend takes the job, agreeing to give the first pilot half in order to borrow the plane or all if he is killed.

And the baby is saved:

The pilot is injured on landing and knocked unconscious, but he crawls to a nearby farm house after he recovers. The farmer sees the box containing the serum and telephones the hospital, and the baby is saved.

I found it with the prompt "old movie pilot delivers medicine to child".
And here are the stars Jimmy Stewart and Carole Lombard:

